# Unable to mount NFS export unless I sudo to root

Tags: filesystems, nfs, sudo, root

I created an NFS export on a GPFS/SpectrumScale filesystem I set up.  I tested the NFS export on a xLinux, pLinux, z/OS and AIX succesfully. I then enabled AD based authentication on the NFS export through SpectrumScale and tested it by logging into each platform with a userid/password combo in the domain I setup the authentication with successfully

I then added the NFS mount point to /etc/fstab on a linux client vm so it automounts when someone logs in.

```
NFShost:/ibm/zixf401/NFS      /crenfs         nfs4    defaults        0 0
```

I logged in with my id an typed df -h which displayed:

```
10.0.4.61:/ibm/zixf401/NFS 2.0T  2.6G  2.0T   1%    /crenfs
```

The problem I have however, which I can not figure out is that I can only access the /crenfs mount if I sudo su first.  If I do not sudo I get the following error:

```
-sh-4.1$ cd /crenfs
-sh: cd: /crenfs: Permission denied
```

Is there a way I can access the /crenfs mount without sudo?

I have seen posts where people enter usernames and passwords in the fstab entry but we will likely have 100+ users accessing this when its set up correctly so we can hardcode credentials into fstab unless we could enter some type of variable that was tied to what they enter when they log in to the machine itself?

Comment: What does `ls -lh /crenfs` say?

Comment: without sudo

`-sh-4.1$ ls -lh /crenfs
ls: cannot open directory /crenfs: Permission denied`

With Sudo:


`

Comment: With Sudo:

`drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nobody 4.0K Feb  3 13:49 automountdir<br/>
drwxrwx--- 2 nobody nobody 4.0K Feb  3 14:45 Closed<br/>
drwxrwx--- 2 nobody nobody 4.0K Feb  3 15:03 Open<br/>
drwx------ 2 nobody nobody 4.0K Feb  3 15:04 testing`

Comment: try `sudo chmod a+rx /crenfs` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @ThoriumBR:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /crenfs
```

Solved this problem